# How can I use SimpleSC with Dependencies in NSIS

Tags: windows-services, installation, nsis

I've this structure of my project(example): 
`Installer\Dependencies\Myservice.exe` 
`Installer\Dependencies\dependenci.dll` 
`Installer\Dependencies\js\file.js` 
`Installer\Dependencies\resources\folder\file.js` 
In each one of these folders I've my dependencies to services install fine.
How can I use the simpleSC to install service if dependencies?

I know the statement: 
`SimpleSC::InstallService [name_of_service] [display_name] [service_type][start_type]   [binary_path] [dependencies] [account] [password]` 
and I already try this, but isn't working: 
`SimpleSC::InstallService "LprService" "LprService" "272" "2" "$INSTDIR\GeneteLPRService.exe" "Dependencies" "" ""` 
P.s.: Using InstallUtil.exe, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleSC dependencies is a list of other services that have to be started before your service can start.

[The Wiki page](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/NSIS_Simple_Service_Plugin) has an example:

```
; Depends on "Windows Time Service" (w32time) and "WWW Publishing Service" (w3svc):
SimpleSC::InstallService "MyService" "My Display Name" "16" "2" "$InstDir\MyService.exe" "w32time/w3svc" "" ""
Pop $0
```

If you don't have any service dependencies then you can just use a empty string like the other unused parameters.

Files required by your service can be installed normally with `File` or `File /r`.

Comment: Hey Anders, thanks a lot. Looks like you help me in all these requests in here!! lol